# Auto expanding all lazy loded configured nodes

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, observable, primeng

How to automatically expand all subnodes (configured to lazy load) from a parent node using observables and primeng?

The console outputs

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

```
expandAll(event) {
this.nodeService.getChildren(event.node.object_sqn).subscribe((nodes) => {
  event.node.children = nodes
});
console.log(event.node.children)
if (event.node.children.count > 0) {
  event.node.expanded = true;
  for (let cn of event.node.children) {
    this.expandAll(cn);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: At the point where your `if()` statement is called, `event` doesn't have the property `children`. You need to move your if statement inside the subscription, or wait for the observable to emit a value, then act on it. Look into the `.pipe()` operator in rxjs

Comment: That approach would work, despite the fact that the method is recursive?

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. `expandAll()` expects an event, yet you're handing in `cn` which is a different type of object.